# How to allow discord bot to access google products?

Tags: python, api, google-sheets, discord.py

I have created a discord bot that requires access to my Google Sheets and Google Calendar. To do so, I have created a project on google console and enabled the drive, sheets, and other required APIs. Then I downloaded the credentials and renamed it as `creds.json`.

Here's what I did to access a spreadsheet named `Responses` from my Google account.

```
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('creds.json', scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

sheet = client.open('Responses')
```

This was all done on my local system. But now, I want anyone to be able to invite this bot and allow it to access their Google products like Sheets, Calendar, etc. so that the bot can do its job. How can I automate this process of enabling the APIs and using the credentials for the inviter? Or is there any other approach?

Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your scenario correctly, you just created an app that runs some operations over different Workspace services. If that is correct, then you could share your app with different users. You should keep in mind that those users would be running the code, but in the end the script will interact with Workspace as if it were your own account. So I recommend you to watch out for any sensitive data manipulation and create dedicated credentials if needed. Here is more info on how to use [OAuth 2.0 in Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2), please take a look at it, specially at the part of enabling the credentials consent. Finally, I recommend you to evaluate [web apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) and see if they are useful in your scenario.

Comment: Thank for the answer. I think you understood the scenario correctly. "You should keep in mind that those users would be running the code, but in the end, the script will interact with Workspace as if it were your own account" exactly this. But how can I ask the user to log in from their Google account when they invite my bot to their server? After that, the bot can use their Google service like calendar to create channels, etc. And yes, I'll keep this in mind "So I recommend you to watch out for any sensitive data manipulation and create dedicated credentials if needed".

Comment: The best approach varies based on the actual operations that the bot will run. I advise you to take a look at [web apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) and [add-ons](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/overview).